# A system with a hidden mistake

Tags: logic, euclidean-geometry

Consider the square $ABCD$ such that $l$ is the length of one side and $x$ is the lenght of the segment $OA$, where $O$ is the center of the square. If the perimeter of the triangle $AOB$ is $24$ and the perimeter of the triangle $ACD$ is $34$, find the area of the square $ABCD$.

So, let us write mathematically the given hypothesis. We have that
$$
2x+l=24,\qquad 2x+2l=34.
$$
The system has a unique solution $(x,l)=(7,10)$. But if $l=10$, by Pitagora's theorem, then $x=5\sqrt{2}$. So, I don't see where is the problem. Why we get two, even three, different results when come back to geometric configuration?

Comment: Because the question is poorly written. Also note that $5\sqrt2 \approx 7.071$, so the person who wrote the question probably did not expect people to check the result via Pythagoreas.

Answer (score 1):

The second information is unnecessary (and causes problem). We know that the length of the diagonal of the square is $l\sqrt2$ and that the diagonals bisect each other. Only using the fact that the perimeter of  $\bigtriangleup AOB$ is $24$:
$$l+\frac{l\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{l\sqrt2}{2}=24$$
which gives: $$l = 24 \;(\sqrt2 - 1)$$